# Ubuntu not finding free space to continue installing

Tags: system-installation, virtualbox

During installation, Ubuntu detects that I don't have at least 6.7 GB available free space, what should I do?

Comment: Welcome! What OS do you have installed?

Comment: What partition size you try to install Ubuntu to? Have you disabled safe boot in bios?

Comment: I'm trying to install ubuntu desktop on virtualbox. I'm working on windows 10

Comment: Recreate your VB virtual disk, and instead of taking the default of 10G size, make it 20G variable size.

Answer (score 1):

Recreate your VB virtual disk, and instead of taking the default of 10G size, make it 20G variable size. 
answered by: **heynnema**